# Getting AUC from sklearn using preds from Statsmodel instance

Tags: python, scikit-learn, statsmodels

I have a logistic regression that I want to know the AUC for.

I created the logistic regression model using `statsmodels`:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = generate_data(dependent_var) # pseudocode
X = generate_data(independent_var) # pseudocode

X['constant'] = 1

logit_model=sm.Logit(y,X)
result=logit_model.fit()
```

Then, I use `sklearn` to get an AUC score for my model predictions:

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(y, result.predict())
```

The code runs and I get a AUC score, I just want to make sure I am passing variables between the package calls correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Input for `roc_auc_score` :

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score.html

`sklearn.metrics.roc_auc_score(y_true, y_score, *, average='macro', sample_weight=None, max_fpr=None, multi_class='raise', labels=None)[source]`

*y_true array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_classes)*

```
True labels or binary label indicators. The binary and multiclass cases expect labels with shape (n_samples,) while the multilabel case expects binary label indicators with shape (n_samples, n_classes).
```

*y_score array-like of shape (n_samples,) or (n_samples, n_classes)*

```
Target scores.
```

To validate the input parameters:

y_true: correct

y_score: result.predict(X), based on https://www.statsmodels.org/devel/examples/notebooks/generated/predict.html

But your validation is missing the concept of `train and test`split wich is necassary in machine learning. Normally you always divide the dataset in a training part and in a test part. In a pseudo code this would look like:

```
import statsmodels.api as sm

y = generate_data(dependent_var) # pseudocode
X = generate_data(independent_var) # pseudocode

X['constant'] = 1
#pseudo line
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split
logit_model=sm.Logit(y_train,X_train)
result=logit_model.fit()

from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(y_test, result.predict(X_test))
```